# Refresh UCWA token automatically on Skype For Business Online

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I've developed an application using UCWA and the password token. I'm reading all the messages coming to the user authenticated with the application using events, but the token doesn't last long and the renewal is using the browser, which is terrible regarding automatisation.

Is there a way of getting a token which doesn't need the renewal via browser so I can have my application fully automatised? I've read all the documentation on Github and on the ucwa website.

This is the request I do to get a token.

Get the signin url

def get_signin_url(redirect_uri, client_id, tenant, resource):
    xframe, user_discovery_uri, resource = do_autodiscover(config['domain'])

```
# Build the query parameters for the signin url
params = {
  'client_id': client_id,
  'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
  'response_type': 'token',
  'response_mode': 'form_post',
  'resource': resource
}

# The authorize URL that initiates the OAuth2 client credential flow for admin consent
authorize_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/%s/oauth2/authorize?{0}' % tenant)

# Format the sign-in url for redirection
signin_url = authorize_url.format(urlencode(params))

return signin_url
```

After several steps, get the token:

```
def get_token_from_code(client_id, tenant, auth_code, redirect_uri, resource, client_secret):

  # Build the post form for the token request
  post_data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': auth_code,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'resource': resource,
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret
  }

  # The token issuing endpoint
  token_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/{0}/oauth2/token'.format(tenant))

  # Perform the post to get access token
  response = requests.post(token_url, data=post_data)

  try:
    # try to parse the returned JSON for an access token
    access_token = response.json()['id_token']
    return access_token
  except:
    raise Exception('Error retrieving token: {0} - {1}'.format(
      response.status_code, response.text))
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are using python.  Is there a reason you are not making use of the [ADAL library for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) to acquire the token without using a broswer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my main problem is not with the Active Directory token, but with the UCWA one, which is different. Although I'll try in case I can improve my solution using ADAL and the answer from Andrey Markeev. :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Although documentation says for some reason that you need implicit flow, in fact Skype for Business Online works perfectly well with normal authorization_token + refresh_token approach.

I think they just haven't documented it yet. Because this approach works with all other Office365 APIs, it's very unlikely that it will be removed.

So after you authorize the user once, you need to do - exactly as you have in your code:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
{
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  code: authorization_code,
  redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret: client_secret
}
```

, **but** then from response you get access_token AND **refresh_token**. refresh_token should be saved somewhere (e.g. in database) for later use.

Now, you use `access_token`, but then at some point you receive 403, and now you can refresh it using the `refresh_token` you saved previously:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
{
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret
}
```

Experience shows that refresh token request can be performed even if significant time has passed since access_token has expired.

I'm using this approach in several applications that use Office 365 APIs, including one that interacts with Skype for Business, and so far there weren't any problems with it.

In terms of official documentation, refresh_token is documented for many subsystems (not for Skype for Business at the time of writing), and everywhere it works almost identically. For example here's such documentation for Azure AD:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I got an automatised solution but It's not optimal, so I'm gonna try what you suggested and let you know if it went well.

Thank you for your help! :-)